# How to check usertype in asp.net

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I am trying to make a website with asp.net.

I've got users table with different users, they all have their own usertype, by defauly it's "U" as in User.
For admins it's "A" as in administrator.

My website also has a header section. I want my code to read which usertype currently has the session active and assign the header menu with either UserHome if it's "U" usertype, or Adminpanel if it's "A" usertype.

How do i do that? I tried this way, but it didn't work.

```
public void checkUserType()
{
    String CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BoothsConnectionString1"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from Users", con);
        con.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        sda.Fill(dt);

        string Utype;
        Utype = dt.Rows[0][5].ToString().Trim();
        if (Utype == "U")
        {

            userhome.Visible = true;
            adminpanel.Visible = false;
        }
        if (Utype == "A")
        {
            adminpanel.Visible = true;
            userhome.Visible = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want to do this *properly*, then instead record the `userType` value as a `Claim` inside your `ClaimsIdentity` so you can get it without needing to hit your database on every request. You shouldn't read every column and row from `Users`, finally you can't disposing of your `SqlCommand` object.

Comment: also, in a equals statement of alpha characters I always set it to lowercase to keep from getting a mismatch because of case. i.e.. if (Utype.ToLower() == 'a' ...

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MVC, you have to look for [Authorize(Roles=Roles.User)] on controller action then redirect to appropriate view.
You can have Roles as a model.In this way you can add any new roles that you may want in future.

Answer (score 0):

```
  public void checkUserType()
{
    String CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BoothsConnectionString1"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from Users", con);
        con.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        sda.Fill(dt);


        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            if (dr["YourUserTypeColumnName"] == "U")
            {

                userhome.Visible = true;
                adminpanel.Visible = false;
            }
            if (dr["YourUserTypeColumnName"] == "A")
            {
                adminpanel.Visible = true;
                userhome.Visible = false;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Please check with this.

Comment: Hello, sir. This doesn't work because it still shows me both of them visible. might be string cast missing

Answer (score 0):

public void checkUserType()

{

```
String CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BoothsConnectionString1"].ConnectionString;
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from Users where usertype"+Your usertype session+"", con);
    con.Open();
    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    sda.Fill(dt);


    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
    {
        if (dr["YourUserTypeColumnName"] == "U")
        {

            userhome.Visible = true;
            adminpanel.Visible = false;
        }
        if (dr["YourUserTypeColumnName"] == "A")
        {
            adminpanel.Visible = true;
            userhome.Visible = false;
        }
    }

}
```

}